# Command prompt window opens and closes immediately while running powershell script

Tags: c#, powershell, command-line, executable, start-process

I'm trying to run a powershell script as follows:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\svn\Services\trunk\Services.In4m.Agent.Host\bin\agent.exe" -Argument --help
```

Any reason why this could be happening. Also, how to write a script so that the command prompt window does not close immediately?

Comment: This is happening because the agent.exe is complete and its closing. You could try  -Wait

Comment: With the -Wait too, it closes. any other solution to this

Comment: Powershell does not honor -wait request

Comment: @the_coder_in_me that is absolutely not true.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the program is ending. If the command just outputs the help text and ends, the window will close upon completion.

Your best bet will be to capture the output from the command and display it out to the user.

```
& "C:\svn\Services\trunk\Services.In4m.Agent.Host\bin\agent.exe" --help | Write-Host
```

If you want to open a separate window and wait for the user to hit enter to close it, you could do something like this:

```
Start-Process 
  -FilePath "powershell.exe" 
  -ArgumentList "& 'C:\svn\Services\trunk\Services.In4m.Agent.Host\bin\agent.exe' --help; Read-Host"
```

It just depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to open agent.exe and hold the window that is triggered by agent.exe running

Comment: Which command above did you run that is ending with the window closing too soon? What happens when you run agent.exe from the command line, independent of PowerShell? Does it immediately return to the command prompt?

Comment: When I run agent.exe from command line .. it pops up a small document in the cmd itself listing all the execution modes and command line parameters I can add...
It does the same when I go inside the folder and run agent.exe from powershell..
Don't know the reason why its reacting when I use an external script to run the same agent.exe file

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the end of your powershell script:
It asks user to press any key and waits until user presses a key.

```
Write-Host "Press any key to continue ...".
$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```

Comment: This will hold the powershell window, not the cmd window that is generated via agent.exe

Comment: Oh you can use noexit tag then.

Comment: @the_coder_in_me The problem sounds like your program.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 this is a common issue with powershell and its not my program. You can try googling it just for reference,